# How to add icon and a line following to next icon vertically

Tags: android, android-layout

[image: icon joining with a line]

It will be better to know if it is possible to do in XML using Linear layout or other layout

Answer (score 2):

You can use Relative,Linear or Constraint

Try inside **Constraint layout**

```
<androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatImageView
    android:id="@+id/ivPlaceHolder"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:padding="4dp"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
    android:src="@drawable/ic_baseline_library_music_24"/>

<View
    android:id="@+id/viewLine"
    android:layout_width="1dp"
    android:layout_height="50dp"
    android:background="@color/teal_200"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/ivPlaceHolder1"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="@+id/ivPlaceHolder"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@+id/ivPlaceHolder"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/ivPlaceHolder" />


<androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatImageView
    android:id="@+id/ivPlaceHolder1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:padding="4dp"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
   app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/viewLine"
    android:src="@drawable/ic_baseline_library_music_24"/>
```

Answer (score 1):

[image]

### Linear Layout Code :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_marginStart="12dp"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView1"
        android:layout_width="32dp"
        android:layout_height="32dp"
        android:contentDescription="@null"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_android_black_24dp"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

    <View
        android:id="@+id/viewLine"
        android:layout_width="2dp"
        android:layout_height="24dp"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:background="#33E24D" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView2"
        android:layout_width="32dp"
        android:layout_height="32dp"
        android:contentDescription="@null"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_android_black_24dp"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can obtain the required result with the help of `LinearLayout`. Change the orientation to vertical in the LinearLayout.

> android:orientation="vertical"

You can use `View` for obtaining the straight line between two images.

This is a sample code for the same. Hope this works for you.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
  android:layout_width="wrap_content"
  android:layout_height="wrap_content"
  android:orientation="vertical">

  <ImageView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    app:srcCompat="@drawable/ic_launcher_background" />

  <View
    android:layout_width="3dp"
    android:layout_height="100dp"
    android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
    android:background="@color/black" />

  <ImageView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    app:srcCompat="@drawable/ic_launcher_background" />
</LinearLayout>
```